# How get value from Edit Text in a RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with an EditText so that the user can add the desired quantity of a product. I am using the Firebase RecyclerView and I am inserting the values ​​into the Firebase database. I am fairly new to Android.

This is My Adapter, after much searching I ended up saving the name of the product and the quantity in ArrayLists, the name of the product that comes from a TextView it's actually being inserted into the Firebase Database, but the Edit Text quantity is not.

```
public class AdaptadorVerduras extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Verduras, AdaptadorVerduras.Holder> {


List<String> nombre = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> cantidad = new ArrayList<>();


public AdaptadorVerduras(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Verduras> options) {
   super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int i, @NonNull Verduras verduras) {
   holder.tv_nombreVerdura.setText(verduras.getNombre());
   holder.tv_cantidadPromedio.setText(String.valueOf(verduras.getCantidad()));
   nombre.add(holder.tv_nombreVerdura.getText().toString());
   cantidad.add(holder.et_Cantidad.getText().toString());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
   return new Holder(view);
}


public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   TextView tv_nombreVerdura, tv_cantidadPromedio;
   ImageView iv_Producto;
   EditText et_Cantidad;

   public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       tv_nombreVerdura = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombreVerdura);
       tv_cantidadPromedio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cantidadPromedio);
       iv_Producto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_Producto);
       et_Cantidad = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_Cantidad);
   }
}
```

This is my Activity. According to what I am trying to do is call the quantity list from my onClick but nothing is happening.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verduras);
    cantidad = findViewById(R.id.et_Cantidad);
    nombre = findViewById(R.id.tv_nombreVerdura);
    bn_Insertar = findViewById(R.id.bn_Insertar);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
   
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Verduras> verduras =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Verduras>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Productos"), Verduras.class)
                    .build();

    adaptadorVerduras = new AdaptadorVerduras(verduras);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorVerduras);

    reference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pedido");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                id = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    bn_Insertar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          
            pedido.setNombre(String.valueOf(adaptadorVerduras.nombre.toString()));
            pedido.setCantidad(String.valueOf(adaptadorVerduras.cantidad.toString()));
            reference.child(String.valueOf(id + 1)).setValue(pedido);
        }


   
    });
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adaptadorVerduras.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adaptadorVerduras.stopListening();
}
```

This is how my DBlooks after inserting the data, as you can see is actually inserting the names but no the quantity.

My Firebase DB:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM40W.png

My App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7l12.png

Comment: Did you try logging the value coming from `EditText`?

Comment: onBindViewHolder will be called and as soon as it is called you are adding in the text from EditText which is empty and you never updated that value, once the user started typing in the text. read https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-recyclerview-work-internally it will help you to design a proper solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a listener class and define a function in it with one String param.
Add that listener in your recyclerView adapter constructor.
Now add 'addTextChangedListener' for your edittext in your viewHiolder class like this:

```
    et_Cantidad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        doSomething();
    } 
});
```

add that function you just defined in the listener in the 'onTextChanged' method. The onTextChanged will retrieve the text from the edittext when you're typing something and pass that text into the listener function.

Now, in the myActivity you'll get the listener function in the adapter class object and you'll get the string from the edittext as you type and then do whatever you want with that text.

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually worked, I just have one more question when I type something in the EditText and delete it and then type a new quantity again is inserting the old  value in the DB too, how can I "delete" this value?

Comment: @jorgesm that's a really good question. I actually never tried it but i guess here's what you can do, since every edittext got it's unique id so you can store the edittext id as key and the text text you're typing in as value. You'll get the id of edittext but just doing this, "edittext.getId()". And whenever you have to show data in the edittext just match the id and fill the edittext with the value. Hope it works! Let me know.